# Cómo reservar memoria para un array de este tipo de estructuras en C

Tags: c

necesito reservar memoria para un array de 4 estructuras definidas así en C. Soy incapaz de hacerlo.

```
typedef struct tiempo {
 int N;           /* tamanio los elementos */
 int n_elems;     /* numero de elementos a promediar */
 double tiempo;   /* tiempo promedio */
 double medio_ob; /* numero premedio de veces que se ejecuta la OB */
 int min_ob;      /* minimo de ejecuciones de la OB */
 int max_ob;      /* maximo de ejecuciones de la OB */
} TIEMPO, *PTIEMPO;
```

Estoy probando así de entre otras maneras pero siempre recibo errores:

```
PTIEMPO tiempo = NULL;
tiempo = malloc(4*sizeof(*tiempo));
```

Muchísimas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola Marcos, bienvenido a [es.so]!. Puedes añadir esos errores que recibes? Has depurado la aplicacion para ver donde puede estar el error?  Es importante que añadas lo investigado para que podamos ayudarte en tu problmea concreto. Recuerda leer el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio asi como [ask] para mejorar las preguntas. Un saludo ^^

Answer (score 3):

El problema es que, cuando haces esto:

```
typedef struct tiempo {
 int N;           /* tamanio los elementos */
 int n_elems;     /* numero de elementos a promediar */
 double tiempo;   /* tiempo promedio */
 double medio_ob; /* numero premedio de veces que se ejecuta la OB */
 int min_ob;      /* minimo de ejecuciones de la OB */
 int max_ob;      /* maximo de ejecuciones de la OB */
} TIEMPO, *PTIEMPO;
```

Lo que estás haciendo es declarar dos variables: `TIEMPO` y `*PTIEMPO` de tipo `tiempo`, y a su vez, estás declarando el tipo `tiempo`.

Esto, tiene errores por donde quieras:

```
PTIEMPO tiempo = NULL;
tiempo = malloc(4*sizeof(*tiempo));
```

Ya que `PTIEMPO` es un puntero de tipo `tiempo` y lo estás usando como tipo de dato, a su vez, `tiempo` ya está declarado como un tipo de dato estrutura. Un tipo de dato no es una variable, es como si trataras de hacer `var int=4;`.

Como `PTIEMPO` ya está declarada como puntero a un tipo de dato `tiempo`, lo que haces es directamente:

```
PTIEMPO=NULL;
PTIEMPO=(tiempo *) malloc(sizeof(tiempo)*4);
```

Con la última línea, estoy diciendo que le voy a reservar memoria a `PTIEMPO`, cuánta? Pues, lo que ocupe la estructura `tiempo` 4 veces. Y a su vez, estoy diciendo que la variable `PTIEMPO` es de tipo *puntero tiempo*.

No sé si tu código tiene fallas en otro lado, pero si todo está bien, debería funcionar directamente con lo anterior.

Y si falla en alguna de esas líneas, podrías probar con esto:

```
    PTIEMPO=NULL;
    PTIEMPO=(struct tiempo *) malloc(sizeof(struct tiempo)*4);
```

Espero te sirva, saludos!

Comment: Un detalle. Aunque es verdad que el código del usuario tiene muchos errores, no es cierto que `tiempo` fuera un tipo. El tipo que define el usuario se llama `struct tiempo`, no `tiempo`.

Comment: El problema es que la estructura la tengo definida en el fichero .h y el malloc lo quiero hacer en una función del .c

Comment: No importa en dónde esté definido el tipo de dato, tienes que tener lo único, cuidado al usar las variables y eso y fijarte de no usar palabras ya usadas por ti.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración abulafia!